# youtube iframe api player.playVideo() doesnt work

Tags: javascript, youtube, youtube-iframe-api

Im trying force autoplay when the youtube video is ready.

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div id="player"></div>
    <br/>
    <button id="botaoPlay" onclick="playMusic()">play</button>
 <script>
      
var tag = document.createElement('script');

tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);
var player;
var timeout = null;

function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
  player = new YT.Player('player', {
    height: '360',
    width: '640',
    videoId: '8t3EHHhkC34',
    playerVars: { autoplay: 1 , enablejsapi: 1, playsinline: 1, origin: 'http://localhost' },
    events: {
      'onReady': onPlayerReady,
      'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange,
      'onError': onPlayerError
    }
  });
}

// 4. The API will call this function when the video player is ready.
function onPlayerReady(event) {
    event.target.setVolume(65);
    if(!timeout)
        timeout = setInterval(playMusic, 1000);
}

function playMusic() {
    if (player) {
        player.playVideo();
    }
}

function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
   console.log("status changed: " + player.getPlayerState());
   if(  player.getPlayerState() == 1  ){
    clearInterval(timeout);
   }
}
</script>
  </body>
</html>
```

But the video only starts if i click on button... how can i start the video? I tried instead call playVideo() in interval, call button.click() but didnt work too, only if i click with mouse in button. How can i start my video without click on button?